# Two classes in diffrence packages how to isolate them?

Tags: java, class, package, names

We have to develope a game, where the user can upload their code, for example Rock Paper Scissor. They have to implement some methods from an interface class  and we call them in our game Class, nothing special.

The code of the users are in packages, that we have no name-collision,
but to the main topic: How we can ensure, that user A don't call methods from the class of user B ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all guesses, but look to:

- Security managers
- Checking the bytecode for illegal actions (e.g. with ASM)
- A seperate Classloader for each game

Alternatively, you could let users upload scripts instead of real Java code, e.g. ECMAScript which you can run with Rhino.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to load the two classes in different class loaders.  To be completely safe, you also need to run the classes in a security sandbox that stops reflection and other mechanisms that could get around the class loader barrier.

---

Actually, I think there might be a flaw in this.  If the two "player" classes implement the same interface, they can polymorpically invoke methods defined in the shared interface.  The fact that they are loaded in different class loaders and therefore can't use each others' types doesn't stop that.

So, you are essentially relying on blocking reflection (and good programming) to prevent one class/object ferreting out the instance of the other.  Blocking reflection also prevents one class from breaking the other's encapsulation, or calling methods that are not defined in a common superclass or a shared interface.

Comment: That would certainly be good to prevent the name collisions, but I don't think it prevents cross-communication between games (if one can somehow get a handle to another one)

Comment: I think that's how OSGi does it - you get lot's of NoClassDefFound errors if You misconfigure the bundle.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom - you are right.  Updated my answer to address this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

If you include, and run some one elses code in your program, nothing prevents them from calling your methods.

You could make your methods package private and seal the packages, and so on, but you would still have to deal with reflection etc.

If I where you, I would consider interfacing with the user-code through a well defined network protocol or through standard input / output.

Comment: I believe private methods can be secured from reflection with a security manager, but I have no experience whatsoever there.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way can be making sure that all methods have `protected` or `default` [access modifier](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) so that no one outside the package can access them.

Comment: But i need access to the methods, because my main class of the game, call the classes from the users.
I start the whole program with the Security Manager, so they have no file access...

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as long as those are public methods, unless you isolate in different class loaders, in which case each class cannot see each other.

Loading in different classloaders is how web containers, like Tomcat, Jetty etc.. isolate different web applications.

Another approach could be to setup a custom security implementation, but it's far harder to make it right than the classloader solution.